# JPA/Hibernate transaction issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wish I could generate primary key with the option TABLE and I don't understand why the transactions doesn't works. 
Here is my environnement (this is an example, not the true application, but it will easyer to explain) :

SGBD : MySql

DataBase : emp, job, department (Oracle example) and pkeys for generation of primary keys

ORM : JPA with Hibernate

Enterprise Application : EmployeeJPA with 2 modules : EmployeeJPA-ejb and EmployeeJPA-war

EJB Entity : Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByEmployeeId", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.employeeId = :employeeId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByName", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByManagerId", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.managerId = :managerId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findByHiredate", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.hiredate = :hiredate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Employee.findBySalary", query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.salary = :salary")})
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @TableGenerator(name="EmployeePk", table="pkeys", pkColumnName="pkey_id",
            valueColumnName="pkey_val", pkColumnValue="EMPLOYEE", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="EmployeePk")    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Integer employeeId;
    . . .
```

EJB Session EmployeeFacade

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class EmployeeFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeesJPA-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @EJB
    JobFacade jobFacade;
    @EJB
    DepartmentFacade departmentFacade;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void addEmployee(String name, Date hiredate, double salary, int jobId, int departmentId, int managerId) throws Exception {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        try{
            Department department = departmentFacade.getDepartmentById(departmentId);
            Job job = jobFacade.getJobById(jobId);
            employee.setDepartment(department);
            employee.setJob(job);
            employee.setHiredate(hiredate);
            employee.setManagerId(managerId);
            employee.setName(name);
            em.persist(employee);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Servlet SrvlEmployee

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String error = null;
    try {
        Date hiredate = Utilitaire.StrToDate("2020-02-01", "yyyy-MM-dd");
        employeeFacade.addEmployee("Smith", hiredate, 2000.00, 2, 3, 4);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = Utilitaire.getExceptionCause(e);
    } finally {
        request.setAttribute("errorR", error);
        RequestDispatcher dsp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dsp.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

The table pkeys before

[image: The table before inserting an employee]

The table pkeys after

[image: The table after inserting an employee]

The last id of the table employee is 14

The requests an the error message :

Hibernate: select department0_.department_id as departme1_0_0_, department0_.dname as dname2_0_0_, department0_.location as location3_0_0_ from department department0_ where department0_.department_id=?

Hibernate: select job0_.job_id as job_id1_2_0_, job0_.jobname as jobname2_2_0_ from job job0_ where job0_.job_id=?

Hibernate: select pkey_val from pkeys where pkey_id = 'EMPLOYEE' for update

Hibernate: update pkeys set pkey_val = ? where pkey_val = ? and pkey_id = 'EMPLOYEE'

Hibernate: insert into employee (department_id, hiredate, job_id, manager_id, name, salary, employee_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000

Duplicate entry '14' for key 'PRIMARY'

It seems that there is not only one transaction but two but I don't understand why !
Where is my error ?
Thank's for your help !

Comment: That works fine with EclipseLink and j2ee.platform 1.6 !!!??? Does anybody unterstand anything ?

Comment: And j2ee.platform 1.7 also